# mongodb spring configuration is throwing exception

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, hibernate

org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:28017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream

WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:28017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]

Comment: Where are the codes! please read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you post your question.

Comment: i fixed this, the issue was the port number , mongodb has default driver port as 27017.